# Open Powershell file as fast as possible with Python

Tags: python, powershell, optimization, tkinter

Currently I'm loading a Powershell file which returns me a value. Is there a way to load it faster? Because my program is opening 8 .ps1 files at the moment and it takes 10 to 15 seconds till the program is ready to use. Can I start the program and later put the strings in it when the program is already running? (because it's a Tkinter GUI)

```
p = subprocess.check_output(["powershell.exe", "C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps1"])
bios = str(p)
if bios == 'b\'[BIOS:config:Network:MACAdressPassThr]disabled\\n\\r\\n\'':
    bios = '[BIOS:config:Network:MACAdressPassThr]\tdisabled'
else:
    bios = '[BIOS:config:Network:MACAdressPassThr]\tenabled'
```

Comment: Maybe the Powershell script can be made faster, but that's hard to say without seeing its contents.

Comment: I would highly suggest you avoid multi threading with tkinter it will make your GUI laggy or it has in my experience anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "till the program is ready"? Are the 8 psl files independent of each other? If they are, you could use the `multiprocessing` module to run all of them concurrently — which would make your program "ready" sooner.

Comment: @martineau I'm opening a GUI and there's obviously the possibility to give a user input. But the problem is that I currently print out BIOS settings which I get from the .ps1 files. And the user can do his input after those Settings are loaded and printed. But I want to give the user the possibility to do inputs before the settings are printed because they are used rarely and they need 10 to 15 seconds as i said.

Comment: I was just suggesting a faster way to run them all. However you do it, the code that does it can be run in a separate thread. The main thread can be the GUI and it can also run while this is being done. The GUI can poll the other thread to know when it's done. The universal tkinter [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method can be used to do this. There are numerous examples of that being done on this website.

Answer (score 0):

You could try if this is faster:

```
import os

os.system("cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps1")
```

Also, I believe your script is executing the scripts in powershell sequentially. I don't know if there is a data dependence between the scripts, but if there is not, you could consider using threads to concurrently run all your scripts:

```
import os
import threading

cmds =  [
            "cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps1",
            "cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps2",
            "cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps3",
            "cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps4",
            "cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps5",
            "cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps6",
            "cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps7",
            "cmd /c powershell C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps8"
        ]

def thread_function(index):
    os.system(cmds[index])

for i in range(len(cmds)):
    x = threading.Thread(target = thread_function, args = (i, ))
    x.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put your string into a label you can use the .configure() method to change the label after its creation. So you could create you tkinter GUI and use .configure() to update it after your powershell completes. If you have any buttons that are used you can wait to display them later or disable them until the powershell command completes.

```py
myLabel.configure(text=bios)
```

or you could use a stringVar to update it.

```py
bios = StringVar()
myLabel = Label(root, textvariable=bios)

p = subprocess.check_output(["powershell.exe", "C:\\PowershellFiles\\bios_settings.ps1"])
    bios.set(str(p))
    if bios.get() == 'b\'[BIOS:config:Network:MACAdressPassThr]disabled\\n\\r\\n\'':
        bios.set('[BIOS:config:Network:MACAdressPassThr]\tdisabled')
    else:
        bios.set('[BIOS:config:Network:MACAdressPassThr]\tenabled')
```

However, your unprocessed string would flash up there for a split second.